# code runs correct on console but not in actual code

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts and am manually positioning the vaxis titles by

```
$($('text').filter(':contains("Recurrence Interval")')[0]).attr('x', '220');
$($('text').filter(':contains("Hazard Score")')[0]).attr('x', '50');
$($('text').filter(':contains("Hazard Score")')[0]).attr('y', '225');
```

The thing is that the first line works 100% fine. The next two lines don't seem to work when in my code. However when I run the bottom two lines in my console, it works. This is all wrapped by a google chart setOnLoadCallBack function so the charts should have been loaded already.

Comment: you should be using the google chart's helper methods to do any modification to the charts.. I don't think `attr` method call doesn't invoke any bindings in the chart library.

Comment: @Minato There actually aren't any helper methods to help me modify the axis titles and everywhere I've looked suggested to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to wait for the chart's `'ready'` event to fire,
before making modifications

set the event listener before drawing the chart, e.g.

```
var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartDiv);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  $($('text').filter(':contains("Recurrence Interval")')[0]).attr('x', '220');
  $($('text').filter(':contains("Hazard Score")')[0]).attr('x', '50');
  $($('text').filter(':contains("Hazard Score")')[0]).attr('y', '225');
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

if animation is being used, listen for the `'animationfinish'` event instead